# LTTng dynamic tracing for Erlang : 'depth' field

Tags: erlang, lttng

I've started to use lttng dynamic tracing for analyzing function call
durations during load tests. I'm collecting 'function_call' and
'function_return' tracepoints for that. My current problem is that if any
loss of trace records happens (and it does happen at the peek of the system
load), analyzing the call stack becomes difficult. Namely, if the
'function_return' record gets lost, it'll look like the matching call was
never returned, which will distort the tracing of the process stack. Also,
there are calls like erlang:throw/1, that never return, by design.
Now, the 'depth' field, which I understand is there to show the stack
depth, would help a lot, but it always seems to show '0' value, regardless
of the actual stack depth. Any suggestions as to how to make 'depth' field
work?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out, the 'depth' field is not currently supported:

https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-355